# Boost.Serialize: writing a general map serialization function

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++17, boost-serialization

Boost.Serialize provides explicit serialization for std::map / std::multimap, which won't work with other map-like containers.

I'd like to serialize those without needing to rewrite these functions every time, but Boost complains about ambiguousness.

Here is my code:

```
/** Some sfinae to detect types that behave like std::map **/
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_map_ish : std::false_type { };

template<template<typename K, typename V> typename Map, typename K, typename V>
struct is_map_ish<
    Map<K,V>,
    std::void_t<
        typename Map<K,V>::key_type,
        typename Map<K,V>::value_type
    >
    > : std::true_type {
};

template<class Archive, class Map>
inline auto save(
    Archive & ar,
    const Map& t,
    const unsigned int /* file_version */,
        std::enable_if_t<is_map_ish<Map>::value>* = 0
) -> std::enable_if_t<is_map_ish<Map>::value>
{
    boost_155::serialization::stl::save_collection<
        Archive,
        Map
    >(ar, t);
}

template<class Archive, class Map>
inline auto load(
    Archive & ar,
    Map& t,
    const unsigned int /* file_version */,
        std::enable_if_t<is_map_ish<Map>::value>* = 0
) -> std::enable_if_t<is_map_ish<Map>::value> {
    boost_155::serialization::stl::load_collection<
        Archive,
        Map,
        boost_155::serialization::stl::archive_input_map<
            Archive, Map >,
            boost_155::serialization::stl::no_reserve_imp<Map>
    >(ar, t);
}

// split non-intrusive serialization function member into separate
// non intrusive save/load member functions
template<class Archive, class Map>
inline auto serialize(
    Archive & ar,
    Map &t,
    const unsigned int file_version,
    std::enable_if_t<is_map_ish<Map>::value>* = 0
) -> std::enable_if_t<is_map_ish<Map>::value> {
    boost_155::serialization::split_free(ar, t, file_version);
}
```

the `serialize` function collides with

```
// default implementation - call the member function "serialize"
template<class Archive, class T>
inline void serialize(
    Archive & ar, T & t, const BOOST_155_PFTO unsigned int file_version
){
    access::serialize(ar, t, static_cast<unsigned int>(file_version));
}
```

in boost, which I obviously cannot change. I tried (as visible in the above code) to put some SFINAE in the return type, and in the function arguments list, but that does not help me escape the overload ambiguity.

What are my options ? In C++20 I'd try concepts but here I can only use C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to employ ADL, or use a [Serialization Wrapper](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html).

Because I don't know when to stop, I made the following proof-of-concept. A general roundtrip test that allows:

- allows switching archive types
- optionally providing a wrapping function (in my example we will define `as_map` and `as_multimap` below); The default is the identity function
- serializes a "map-ish container" of 4 entries into a stringstream
- deserializes it back
- compares the replica to the original

```
template <typename OA, typename IA, template <typename...> class Map,
          typename WrapFun = std::identity>
void roundtrip_impl(std::string_view archive_type, WrapFun apply_wrap = {})
{
    using Container = Map<int, std::string>;
    Container original{{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}, {4, "four"}};

    using namespace boost::archive;
    std::stringstream ss;

    {
        OA oa(ss, archive_flags::no_header);
        auto&& payload = apply_wrap(original);
        oa << boost::make_nvp("data", payload);
    }

    std::cout << archive_type << " "
              << (typename boost::serialization::is_wrapper<decltype(
                          apply_wrap(original))>::type{}
                      ? "Wrapped "
                      : "Builtin ")
              << std::setw(3) << ss.str().length() << " bytes" << std::flush;

    {
        IA ia(ss, archive_flags::no_header);
        Container replica;
        auto&& payload = apply_wrap(replica);
        ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("data", payload);

        std::cout << " - roundtrip verified: " << std::boolalpha
                  << (original == replica) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now to get systematic, we will define an test entry point that exercises all the archive type:

```
template <template <typename...> class Map, typename WrapFun = std::identity>
void roundtrips(WrapFun do_wrap = {})
{
    roundtrip_impl<
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive,
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
        Map>("Binary", do_wrap);
    roundtrip_impl<
        boost::archive::text_oarchive,
        boost::archive::text_iarchive,
        Map>("Text  ", do_wrap);
    roundtrip_impl<
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive,
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive,
        Map>("XML   ", do_wrap);
}
```

> This specifically verifies that the wrapper works in the presence of NVP wrappers.

### A Serialization Wrapper

For map-ish containers without builtin library support, let's create a wrapper:

```
namespace Serialization {
    template <typename Map, typename Unique = std::true_type> struct map_wrapper {
        Map& ref;
        map_wrapper(Map& m) : ref(m) {}

        constexpr static bool is_unique = Unique::value;
    };
```

Adding some convenience functions `as_map` and `as_multimap`:

```
struct {
    constexpr auto operator()(auto& ref) const { return map_wrapper(ref); }
} static inline constexpr as_map;

struct {
    constexpr auto operator()(auto& ref) const {
        return map_wrapper<decltype(ref), std::false_type>(ref);
    }
} static inline constexpr as_multimap;
```

Now we can implement generic save/load for the wrapper:

```
// ADL finds these
template <typename Ar, typename... Args>
void save(Ar& ar, map_wrapper<Args...> const& w, unsigned v) {
    size_t n = std::size(w.ref);
    ar & boost::make_nvp("size", n);
    for (auto& element : w.ref) {
        ar & boost::make_nvp("item", element);
    }
}
```

That was straightforwad. Of course, deserialization is somewhat more varied:

```
template <typename Ar, typename Map, typename Unique>
void load(Ar& ar, map_wrapper<Map, Unique>& w, unsigned v)
{
    using V = typename boost::range_value<Map>::type;

    w.ref.clear(); // optionally?
    size_t n;
    ar & boost::make_nvp("size", n);

    while (n--) {
        V element;
        ar & boost::make_nvp("item", element);

        // insert and fix object tracking!
        if constexpr (Unique()) {
            auto [it, inserted] = w.ref.insert(std::move(element));
            if (inserted)
                ar.reset_object_address(std::addressof(*it), &element);
        } else {
            auto it = w.ref.insert(std::end(w.ref), std::move(element));
            ar.reset_object_address(std::addressof(*it), &element);
        }
    }
}
```

The most important bit is where we fixup the object address for address tracking. See [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking).

There is no templatey `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE`, so we write:

```
template <typename Ar, typename... Args>
void serialize(Ar& ar, map_wrapper<Args...>& m, unsigned v)
{
    if constexpr (typename Ar::is_saving())
        save(ar, m, v);
    else
        load(ar, m, v);
}

} // namespace Serialization
```

NEARLY done. We just need to help the library realize we're a wrapper:

```
namespace boost::serialization {
    template <typename... Args>
    struct is_wrapper<Serialization::map_wrapper<Args...>> {
        using type = std::true_type;
    };
    // it's heinous, but we have to do it for const qualified too
    template <typename... Args>
    struct is_wrapper<Serialization::map_wrapper<Args...> const> {
        using type = std::true_type;
    };
} // namespace boost::serialization
```

### Running Some Tests

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eba4bce490efe03b)**

```
// bunch of tests with various containers
```

#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/set.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

```
// including fantasy "maps"
template <typename K, typename V>
    using FakeMap = boost::container::set<std::pair<K, V>>;
template <typename K, typename V>
    using FakeMultiMap = std::vector<std::pair<K, V>>;

int main() 
{
    roundtrips<std::map>();
    roundtrips<std::multimap>();

    roundtrips<std::unordered_map>();
    roundtrips<std::unordered_multimap>();

    // no direct support, but we can wrap!
    using Serialization::as_map;
    using Serialization::as_multimap;
    roundtrips<boost::container::map>(as_map);
    roundtrips<boost::container::multimap>(as_multimap);

    roundtrips<boost::unordered_map>(as_map);
    roundtrips<boost::unordered_multimap>(as_multimap);

    roundtrips<FakeMap>(as_map);
    roundtrips<FakeMultiMap>(as_multimap);
}
```

Prints

```
Binary Builtin  85 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Builtin  47 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Builtin 393 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Builtin  85 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Builtin  47 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Builtin 393 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Builtin  93 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Builtin  49 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Builtin 425 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Builtin  93 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Builtin  49 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Builtin 425 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Wrapped  81 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Wrapped  45 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Wrapped 359 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Wrapped  81 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Wrapped  45 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Wrapped 359 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Wrapped  81 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Wrapped  45 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Wrapped 359 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Wrapped  81 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Wrapped  45 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Wrapped 359 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Wrapped  81 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Wrapped  45 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Wrapped 359 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Binary Wrapped  81 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
Text   Wrapped  45 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
XML    Wrapped 359 bytes - roundtrip verified: true
```

### Caveat

Note in these examples I have **assumed** that the map-ish containers will be using default-constructible comparators/hash function/equality comparators. Otherwise you have to remember to implement `load_/save_construct_data` and at that point I believe you're better off just writing type-specific implementations.

### Full Listing

(anti [bitrot](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eba4bce490efe03b))

```
#include <boost/archive/basic_archive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename OA, typename IA, template <typename...> class Map,
          typename WrapFun = std::identity>
void roundtrip_impl(std::string_view archive_type, WrapFun apply_wrap = {})
{
    using Container = Map<int, std::string>;
    Container original{{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}, {4, "four"}};

    using namespace boost::archive;
    std::stringstream ss;

    {
        OA oa(ss, archive_flags::no_header);
        auto&& payload = apply_wrap(original);
        oa << boost::make_nvp("data", payload);
    }

    std::cout << archive_type << " "
              << (typename boost::serialization::is_wrapper<decltype(
                          apply_wrap(original))>::type{}
                      ? "Wrapped "
                      : "Builtin ")
              << std::setw(3) << ss.str().length() << " bytes" << std::flush;

    {
        IA ia(ss, archive_flags::no_header);
        Container replica;
        auto&& payload = apply_wrap(replica);
        ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("data", payload);

        std::cout << " - roundtrip verified: " << std::boolalpha
                  << (original == replica) << std::endl;
    }
}

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

template <template <typename...> class Map, typename WrapFun = std::identity>
void roundtrips(WrapFun do_wrap = {})
{
    roundtrip_impl<
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive,
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
        Map>("Binary", do_wrap);
    roundtrip_impl<
        boost::archive::text_oarchive,
        boost::archive::text_iarchive,
        Map>("Text  ", do_wrap);
    roundtrip_impl<
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive,
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive,
        Map>("XML   ", do_wrap);
}

#include <boost/range/value_type.hpp>

namespace Serialization {
    template <typename Map, typename Unique = std::true_type> struct map_wrapper {
        Map& ref;
        map_wrapper(Map& m) : ref(m) {}

        constexpr static bool is_unique = Unique::value;
    };

    struct {
        constexpr auto operator()(auto& ref) const { return map_wrapper(ref); }
    } static inline constexpr as_map;

    struct {
        constexpr auto operator()(auto& ref) const {
            return map_wrapper<decltype(ref), std::false_type>(ref);
        }
    } static inline constexpr as_multimap;

    // ADL finds these
    template <typename Ar, typename... Args>
    void save(Ar& ar, map_wrapper<Args...> const& w, unsigned v) {
        size_t n = std::size(w.ref);
        ar & boost::make_nvp("size", n);
        for (auto& element : w.ref) {
            ar & boost::make_nvp("item", element);
        }
    }

    template <typename Ar, typename Map, typename Unique>
    void load(Ar& ar, map_wrapper<Map, Unique>& w, unsigned v)
    {
        using V = typename boost::range_value<Map>::type;

        w.ref.clear(); // optionally?
        size_t n;
        ar & boost::make_nvp("size", n);

        while (n--) {
            V element;
            ar & boost::make_nvp("item", element);

            // insert and fix object tracking!
            if constexpr (Unique()) {
                auto [it, inserted] = w.ref.insert(std::move(element));
                if (inserted)
                    ar.reset_object_address(std::addressof(*it), &element);
            } else {
                auto it = w.ref.insert(std::end(w.ref), std::move(element));
                ar.reset_object_address(std::addressof(*it), &element);
            }
        }
    }

    template <typename Ar, typename... Args>
    void serialize(Ar& ar, map_wrapper<Args...>& m, unsigned v)
    {
        if constexpr (typename Ar::is_saving())
            save(ar, m, v);
        else
            load(ar, m, v);
    }

} // namespace Serialization

namespace boost::serialization {
    template <typename... Args>
    struct is_wrapper<Serialization::map_wrapper<Args...>> {
        using type = std::true_type;
    };
    // it's heinous, but we have to do it for const qualified too
    template <typename... Args>
    struct is_wrapper<Serialization::map_wrapper<Args...> const> {
        using type = std::true_type;
    };
} // namespace boost::serialization

// bunch of tests with various containers
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/set.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

// including fantasy "maps"
template <typename K, typename V>
    using FakeMap = boost::container::set<std::pair<K, V>>;
template <typename K, typename V>
    using FakeMultiMap = std::vector<std::pair<K, V>>;

int main() 
{
    roundtrips<std::map>();
    roundtrips<std::multimap>();

    roundtrips<std::unordered_map>();
    roundtrips<std::unordered_multimap>();

    // no direct support, but we can wrap!
    using Serialization::as_map;
    using Serialization::as_multimap;
    roundtrips<boost::container::map>(as_map);
    roundtrips<boost::container::multimap>(as_multimap);

    roundtrips<boost::unordered_map>(as_map);
    roundtrips<boost::unordered_multimap>(as_multimap);

    roundtrips<FakeMap>(as_map);
    roundtrips<FakeMultiMap>(as_multimap);
}
```

Comment: Aouch. it's good to know that it is possible to achieve, but requiring a wrapper class for that is also what i feared: since I only need it for one container kind in practice, it seems that here the right engineering tradeoff is to not go the generic way as in this case no wrapper will be needed.. and by the time I need it for another container, this codebase will be able to use C++20 and thus concepts which will allow to do what I want without wrapping :|

Comment: The wrapper isn't needed, as you correctly observe, so really no ouch. I don't think concepts change anything here (unless the primary template is removed). And if they did I don't think it would conceptually improve much beyond the syntax required and possibly diagnostics

Comment: I think concepts actually do change, as concept overloads do take precedence over generic ones: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ssbPf6T5c

Comment: Ooh. I thought they would "just compete". Thanks for clarifying. That does seem potentially helpful